# Problem with the flow of program execution resulting unexpected behaviour

Tags: assembly, x86-64, control-flow

I have written an Assembly x64 Assembly code (NASM compatible) that is getting compiled and running on Linux but outputs an unexpected portion of the code.

What this code does is that it takes a string input which is a hex value. It checks if the string is a hex value and then moves forward. It compares it with a hex value of 0x100. If it is equal to 0x100, then it prints the success message. Else, it prints a failed message.

The code is:

```
global _start

section .data

    hex_chars db "ABCDEF0123456789"         ; valid hex characters

    success_message: db "Secret Unlocked", 0x0a     ; success message
    fail_message: db "Vault Locked", 0x0a           ; failed message

    success_message_length: equ $ - success_message
    fail_message_length: equ $ - fail_message

    error_message: db "invalid hex code", 0x0a
    error_message_size: equ $ - error_message

section .bss

    input_buffer resq 16

section .text

_start:

    ; --- main code here --- ;

    ; getting the user input: syscall-read

    mov rax, 0x00
    mov rdi, 0x00
    mov rsi, input_buffer
    mov rdx, 16
    syscall

    mov rdi, rsi            ; hex_to_int takes an value from rdi
    call hex_to_int         ; calling the hex to integer

    ; hex value is in the rax

    cmp rax, 0x100          ; compare the value in rax with 0x100 hex
    je success          ; jump to success function (exit from there)

    ; program will reach here if number is not 0x100, so throw an failed message

    mov rax, 0x01
    mov rdi, 0x01
    mov rsi, fail_message
    mov rdx, fail_message_length
    syscall

    ; exiting with code 0

    mov rax, 0x3c
    mov rdi, 0x00
    syscall

success:

    ; success message

    mov rax, 0x01
    mov rdi, 0x01
    mov rsi, success_message
    mov rdx, success_message_length
    syscall

    ; exiting with code 0

    mov rax, 0x3c
    mov rdi, 0x00
    syscall

hex_to_int:

    ; --- init values --- ;

    xor rax, rax            ; clearing the rax (accumulator)
    xor rcx, rcx            ; clearing the rcx (loop counter)

convert_loop:

    movzx rdi, byte [rdi + rcx] ; get the char from the string
    test rdi, rdi           ; check if it is a null ptr (end of the string)
    jz done             ; if yes, jump to done

    ; check if the char is a valid hex value

    mov rbx, hex_chars      ; load the test values to rbx
    mov rsi, 0          ; init rsi = 0

; rdi contains the char
; rbx contains the hex_chars
; rcx is the program counter

search_loop:

    cmp rdi, [rbx + rsi]        ; take a single char from the hex_value and compare to the char
    je digit_found          ; jump to digit_found function if found

    ; not found!

    add rsi, 1          ; getting ready for the next test char
    cmp rsi, 16         ; check if all hex test cases are completed
    jne search_loop         ; jump to check next hex test char if rsi != 16

    ; if program reaches this point, then exit with an error (not test cases passed -> invalid hex char)

    ; printing the invalid message

    mov rax, 0x01
    mov rdi, 0x01
    mov rsi, error_message
    mov rdx, error_message_size
    syscall

    ; exit with exit code 0

    mov rax, 0x3c
    mov rdi, 0x00
    syscall

digit_found:

    imul rdi, rdi, 16       ; rax = rax * 16
    add rax, rdi            ; building up the hex value

    inc rcx             ; incrementing the program counter
    jmp convert_loop        ; loop back the the convert loop section

done:

    ret

; ---------------------------------------- Notes ---------------------------------------- ;
;
; when refering to a pointer holding some value, it's actually the memory address the registers
; are holding with it.
; Example:
;   rbx = "ABCEDF"
;   rbx is pointing to A
;   rbx + 1 = B
;
;   hence loop over: rsi = 0 to rsi = 6
;       [ rbx + rsi ] will fetch desired values
;
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ;
```

I am keeping my comments as it is for reference.

It is happening that for any number I give as an input, it throws the same "invalid hex code" output which must be executed if the input is not a valid hex character (eg. 0xZZ is invalid). Even if the input is valid for example 0xAA, it interprets it to be invalid.

I expect that this code should run as per intended.

Comment: Not your only problem, but `success_message_length` equate should be put into the very next line after `success_message`.

Comment: When you loop back to `convert_loop` you want to use `rdi` again in `movzx rdi, byte [rdi + rcx]` but it has been overwritten with the byte from the buffer. `cmp rdi, [rbx + rsi]` should be `cmp dil, [rbx + rsi]`. At `digit_found` you still need to convert the hexit to a number in `rdi`, as is you would add the ASCII codepoint. (You could use `rsi` if you ordered the `hex_chars` in the order of their values.) At `digit_found` you should multiply `rax` not the new digit in `rdi`. You're also not capitalising your input anywhere so only capital hexits would work. That should be most of it.

Comment: `input_buffer` should be `resb 16` not `resq 16`. And you may want to check for codepoint 10 (Line Feed) in the input buffer after your read.

Comment: Single-stepping with a debugger would probably have helped you find several of those bugs.  If you do not have an appropriate debugger installed and/or don't know how to use it, I would suggest doing that before you attempt to write or test another line of code.  It's an absolutely essential skill.